# How to Solve Error inflating class fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to archive multiple set (Tablet and Handset) app which has 2 fragments (BaseFragment and BlankFragment). When I run, it shows message and indicate onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) **
**

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class fragment

**

> line 18---  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.santossingh.tablet, PID: 2164

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.santossingh.tablet/com.santossingh.tablet.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
at com.santossingh.tablet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

Here is my codes :
manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.santossingh.tablet"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.santossingh.tablet.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseFragment.onclickedListener{

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public void onSelectedItem(String s) {
    BlankFragment blankFragment=
            (BlankFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id
                    .blankFrg);
    if (blankFragment==null){
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class)
                .putExtra("moviename",s);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        blankFragment.update(s);
    }

}
```

}

2) BaseFragment

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] data;
private onclickedListener onclickedListener;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        data=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_name);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_fragment, R.id.textView, data);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String moviename=data[position];
                onclickedListener.onSelectedItem(moviename);
            }
        });

        return view;
}

public interface onclickedListener{
    public void onSelectedItem(String s);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        onclickedListener=(onclickedListener)context;
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw e;
    }

}
```

}

3) BlankFragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] data2;
    TextView r;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        r=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.result);
        data2=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_detail);

        return view;

    }
    public void update(String s){
        if (s.equals("superman")){
            r.setText(s+" ["+data2[0]+"]");
        }
        else if (s.equals("Hulk")){
            r.setText(s+" ["+data2[0]+"]");
        }
        else if (s.equals("Ironman")){
            r.setText(s+" ["+data2[0]+"]");
        }
        else if (s.equals("Spiderman")){
            r.setText(s+" ["+data2[0]+"]");
        }
        else if (s.equals("Batman")){
            r.setText(s+" ["+data2[0]+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

4) SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        String moviename= getIntent().getStringExtra("moviename");

        BlankFragment blankFragment=(BlankFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R
                .id.blankFrg);
        blankFragment.update(moviename);


    }

}
```

**
*I solve it... it is a minor mistake under the BaseFragment class in onCreateView(), here is the solution :*
**

**

> View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);

**

Comment: post your xml code too, or check the #8 in the xml file. may be you used a large image file.

Comment: Please post the entire logcat

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I have solved it, actually it was a minor mistake in BaseFragment class in onCreateView method just changed { R.layout.fragment_second into R.layout.fragment_base } ... :)

Comment: If you have solved this query you should also post the solution as an answer for others that have the same issue in future. @Santosh

Comment: Oh sorry @Charlie, Now I add it... Thanks :)